# Spring MVC + Hibernate self-join gives error like "id to load is required for loading"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, self-join

I want to design with parent-child logic with hibernate-self join.

**Office Model Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_office")
public class Office implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_ID")
    private Integer officeId;

    @Column(name = "OFFICE_NAME")
    private String officeName;

    @Column(name = "OFFICE_FAX")
    private String officeFax;

    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE")
    private String officePhone;

    @Column(name = "OFFICE_STATUS")
    private String officeStatus;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_OFFICE_ID")
    private Office parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Office> childOffice = new HashSet<Office>();

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

**Office DAO Impl Class**
I have dao class like that methods. Dao is a interface.

```
@Repository
public class OfficeDaoImpl implements OfficeDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addOffice(Office office) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(office);
        session.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public Office getOfficeById(Integer officeId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Office office = (Office) session.get(Office.class, officeId);
        return office;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Office> getAllOffices() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session.createQuery("FROM Office").list();
    }

}
```

**Office Controller Class**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/panel/office")
public class OfficeController {


    @Autowired
    private OfficeService officeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addOfficeGET(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer officeId){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("panel/panel-offices");

        Office office = null;       

        if (officeId != null) {
            office = officeService.getOfficeById(officeId);
        }

        if (office == null) {
            office = new Office();
        }

        mav.addObject("office", new Office());
        mav.addObject("offices", officeService.getAllOffice());
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addOfficePOST(@Valid @ModelAttribute("office") Office office, BindingResult result){
        ModelAndView mav1 = new ModelAndView();
        ModelAndView mav2 = new ModelAndView("panel/panel-offices");
        mav1.setViewName("redirect:/panel/office/add");

        Office parent = null;
        parent= officeService.getOfficeById(office.getParent().getOfficeId());
        office.setParent(parent);

        if (result.hasErrors()) { 
             return mav2;
        }

        if (office.getOfficeId() != null) {
            officeService.officeGuncelle(office);
        } else {
            officeService.OfficeEkle(office);
        }

        return mav1;

    }
```

**Office Service Impl Class**
I have a Service class. this class same as Dao class and it is a interface

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class OfficeServiceImpl implements OfficeService {

    @Autowired
    private OfficeDao officeDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void addOffice(Office office) {
        officeDao.addOffice(office);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
    public List<Office> getAllOffice() {
        return officeDao.getAllOffice();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
    public Birim getOfficeById(Integer officeId) {
        return officeDao.getOfficeById(officeId);
    }

}
```

**panel-offices jsp View page**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="parent">Parent Office Name:</label>
                <form:select path="parent.officeId" class="form-control chosen-full-select">
                    <form:option value="">--Select--</form:option>
                        <c:forEach items="${offices}" var="office">
                            <form:option value="${office.officeId}">${office.officeName}</form:option>
                        </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </div>
```

i want to save "General Manager" with parent value is null. After second record includes "General Manager Assistant" and select "General Manager" from parent List. it gives "*id to load is required for loading*" error when i try to save General Manager parent value is null. But when i do manually insert to database  General Manager with parent is null value.It will be save, but it will save also General Manager Assitant, but i dont want it the manually insert for database.